# Grid of photos in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I lack any knowledge in xcode, cocoa touch or c+++ etc. Now, I am going to try to make a photography app, where I got a tab bar, and 4 undercategories. At the first category, I want it to be a grid of photos who can be enlarged by touching them. I really don't have time to learn more about programming for a couple of months. How is this achieved in the easiest possible way? I am currently leaning towards AQGridView, but since I have zero knowledge of the area I cannot fully understand the instructions. Now before you ask why I want to make an app without any sorts of knowledge, let me answer it. My father is a photographer, and wishes to get an app. If I manage to make one for him, I can get loads of jobs where his photographer friends pay for an app. And if I have already made it, I will probably have a template from the earlier project to take advantage from.

So, in conclusion, my question is: How do I make this possible in the easiest way possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid there are no shortcuts. Go through some iOS tutorials such as http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials and try to learn more before proceeding.

Comment: Sorry but no one here knows C+++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a great candidate for the new UICollectionViews. There are many grid frameworks out there, but if you have any experience with TableViews on iOS, CollectionViews are a breeze to get up and running quickly. One of the best resources for learning and implementing CollectionViews (outside of the API docs) can be found here:

[UICollectionView custom layout tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial)